# Is it possible to save double digit numbers in an unsigned char in c++

Tags: c++, char, unsigned

For a school assignment, i have to save string values from 0 to 255 in an unsigned char vector. normally i would just use strings or ints for this, but we were specifically told to use unisgned char.

After researching more about unsigned chars it seems that it can save the ASCII code 0 to 255 (did i get that correctly?) So is it even possible to save a double (or triple up to 255) digit number in an unsigned char?

Thank you so much. 
Im really sorry, if this is very basic, but im still new to c++.

Comment: `unsigned char ch = 123;` works just fine. What again seems to be the problem?

Comment: `unsigned char` is an integral type, just like `int` and `long`. It is required to be large enough to hold values in the range 0 through 255. Yes, it's also used to hold character codes, but it's not limited to those.

Comment: Okay i forgot to mention that the values are saved as strings. So say i have the ' string str = 123 ' and through sstream i convert it to an unsigned char like ' stringstream sso; ' --> ' sso << str; ' --> ' unsigned char ch; ' --> ' sso >> ch; ' and then read it out by ' std::cout << ch << endl; ' i just get 1

Comment: @m0xpl0x Please don't add details in comments (especially crucial details like this), instead, [edit] your question to add them. People will likely not notice the part in comments)

Comment: Could you please clarify whether your task is to transform a variable like `int a = 123;` into `unsigned char b[] = {1, 2, 3};` or something different?

Comment: I have the number values saved as strings. for example 'string str = 123' and want to save it as an unsigned char in order to add it into an unsigned char vector

Comment: Sounds like you want [`std::stoi` or one of its many friends](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can store up to 255.

Since, `char` is of 8 bits (1 byte), which means it can store upto 256 numbers (2<sup>8</sup> numbers)

- If it is `signed char`, it can store from `-128` to `127`.
- If it is `unsigned char`, it can store from `0` to `255` (only positive numbers).

Just remember, if you have `n` bits:

1. For `signed`: -2<sup>n-1</sup> to 2<sup>n-1</sup>-1.
2. For `unsigned`: 0 to 2<sup>n</sup>-1.

Comment: `char` is not guaranteed to be 8 bits, the C++ Standards says that clearly, see [here](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.fundamental#tab:basic.fundamental.width) and [here](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.fundamental#7.sentence-1). Also, byte is not alwas 8 bits wide (see, e.g., [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte)). The very first question is _The byte is a unit of digital information that **most commonly** consists of eight bits._

Comment: In old Cray computers all integer types were 32 bits. `char`, `short`, `int`, and `long` were all the same size. This makes a byte 32 bits on these computers. [This is 100% legal in C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types). The Standard specifies only a minimum size and that a type cannot be larger than the next larger type. Why not exactly specify? To allow support for hardware like the old Crays.

Answer (score 0):

Despite its name, unsigned char does not hold ASCII (or non-ASCII) characters. It holds integer values stored as a series of bits. Each bit is either 0 or 1. Since there are 8 bits in a char, we have sequences like 10010111, 00010110, 00000010, etc. These are binary (or "base-2") numbers since we only use 2 numerals when writing them ('0' and '1'). When you say a "two-digit" or "three-digit" number in your question, you are talking about our everyday base-10 system that uses 10 numerals (0 to 9) to write numbers. You need to read a bit about base-2 numbers to understand this better. But the basic thing is that an unsigned char holds an integer from 0 to 255, and it doesn't matter how we write it in our everyday human language. The reason they are called char is because historically they were often used to represent a character of text. Basically the integer stored in a char was used to "look up" a character in the ASCII table.

Comment: so unsigned char is not a text or number but sort of "pure data"? is it then possible to convert a string str = 123; as an unsigned char ?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. Now you are talking about parsing a string and converting the "text" to an integer. There are built-in functions to help with this, but I don't know the details. It should be easy to find though.

Answer (score 0):

In an unsigned char you can store number from 0 to 255 so the answer for your question is ***YES***, you can store 3 digit number, but pay attention to not overflow the capacity or you store only the last BITE(or 8 bits) of information.

If you what store it has charaters with their code you need to used signed char, or better an array of signed char, that will be similar to a string.

Comment: So if i have a string str = "255" how can i convert that to an unsigned char and then print it out ?

Comment: Yes, you can do that

Comment: How would you do that ? I tried it with stringstream, but it only prints out the first numer

Comment: Try to see the function c_str() of the string

Comment: Okay i tried either converting the c_str() of the string and ´unsigned char ch = stringname.c_str(); but still it only transfers the first number( so "1" instead of "123"

Comment: To print a `char` type as an integer, either assign it to an integer variable or cast it as an integer variable.  The output system overloads `char` types to print their values as characters, even if they are not printable (such as control characters).

Comment: @moplox look at return type of c_str that is a const char*... you can use it as an array